# How install git on my fedora 16 machine to use as own git server?

Tags: git, fedora16

My team have 3 or 5 person.And we are working locally.

and we decided to choose git server on my laptop so other person can check out...

I have tried something like this:

```
mkdir gitexample
cd gitexample
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@IP_ADDRESS_OF_SERVER:example.git
git push origin master
```

But when I run until the :

```
git remote add origin git@192.168.1.15:example.git
git push origin master
```

I got the message :

```
git@192.168.1.12's password: 
fatal: 'example.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Anybody know how to install and config it on fedora?
`192.168.1.15` is my ip address.

and When I run:

```
[root@localhost .ssh]# ssh git@192.168.1.12
git@192.168.1.12's password: 
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
Connection to 192.168.1.12 closed.
```

Anything else to make it work?

Comment: Did you clone a repository (as bare) and name it `example.git` ?

Comment: How Can we do that @dystroy. I am a newbie.

Comment: `git clone --bare example.git`, then move the created directory to the public location.

Comment: As you are new to git I would recommend using github otherwise you're re-inventing the wheel and adding potential problems to re-solve.  github is $7 a month per person and well worth it.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant github isn't always the solution. For example you can't have many repositories. Using git without github is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server you have to init a bare repository.

```
mkdir example.git
cd example.git
git init --bare
```

After that you'll be able to clone/pull/push from and to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), which is a Git server. Fedora requires no particular procedure here as opposed to any other Linux distribution.

In essence, gitolite manages your repositories by using SSH access. You create a specific user (namely, `git`) to access the repositories, then provide a simple configuration file with user privileges for authorization. You manage authentication by public SSH keys. Creation of repositories and changes of authorization can be performed via a special "administration" repository, while destruction of repositories must be performed manually.

All in all, it is a pretty low-level facility for handling Git repositories. It starts simple but it has a lot of configuration details you can tune. The [quick install](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/qi.html) documentation is pretty straightforward.

In my opinion, gitolite is a good investment also for "local" workgroups. When you have gained confidence with the (very simple) setup procedure, managing repositories becomes a piece of cake.